# Using Oracle rank() in a left join

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this subquery by itself:

```
select * 
from (select rpt_nbr, iteration, seq_nbr, emp_id_key, rank() over
     (partition by   emp_id_key order by iteration, seq_nbr) rk 
      from SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP where rpt_nbr = 1572413) 
where rk = rownum
```

I get a good result it with only 1 `emp_id_key` returned for each iteration and `seq_nbr`, even though there can be multiple `emp_id_key` s assigned.  So that is good, however, when I add that to the rest of my query:

```
select * from 

SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT r 
left join SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC s on s.rpt_nbr = r.rpt_nbr
left join (select * from
    (select rpt_nbr, iteration, seq_nbr, emp_id_key, rank() over (partition by emp_id_key order  
         by iteration, seq_nbr) rk from SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP ) where rk = rownum)
         se on se.rpt_nbr = s.rpt_nbr and se.seq_nbr = s.seq_nbr and se.iteration = s.iteration
left join sjtcapp.employee tech on tech.emp_id_key = se.emp_id_key
```

I get a NULL value for the tech.emp_id_key join

Update:

```
select * from (select rpt_nbr, iteration, seq_nbr, emp_id_key, rank() over (partition by emp_id_key order by iteration, seq_nbr ) rk from SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP where rpt_nbr = 1572413)  where rk = rownum and rpt_nbr = 1572413
```

The above query also gives 'good' results.

```
RPT_NBR ITERATION   SEQ_NBR EMP_ID_KEY  RK
1572413 1   1   44746   1
1572413 1   2   44746   2
```

Before I had more of a straightforward join here and received a correct query with individual technician names.  Only issue is that if more than one were assigned it caused a duplicate, which is why I added the rank subquery.

Comment: If you add `where rpt_nbr = 1572413` to the inner select do you get 1 emp_ID_key again? Could be that you have a one to many that becomes visible again when you remove the limiting criteria.  Or if you remove the `where rpt_nbr = 1572413` from the top query example, does it work the way you want it to?  My suspicion is that either SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT or SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC is causing null values to appear before you join to the inner select which result in null avlues between tech.emp_ID_Key and se.emp_id_key.  would need to see sample data to know (SQLFiddle.Com would help here.)

Comment: `rk = rownum` strikes me as very iffy. It may work as you expect currently, but I don't think you can count on that. There is no guarantee that `rownum` will behave consistently on unordered results.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Changed the query to use rank() in a different way and use rn = 1
'code'left join (select * from
 (select rpt_nbr, iteration, seq_nbr, emp_id_key, rank() over (partition by iteration, seq_nbr order by emp_id_key) rn from SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP ) where rn = 1)
         se on se.rpt_nbr = s.rpt_nbr and se.seq_nbr = s.seq_nbr and se.iteration = s.iteration
'code'

Comment: The Rank() is returning very large values in this query, so I guess I can't use that method for just getting one row.  I tried using a group by method, which worked, but the query took forever.  My issue is that there can be more than one SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP per report but I don't want to count it more than once

Answer (score 0):

If constrain iteration and seq_nbr is unique you can use exists instead rank

```
SELECT
  rpt_nbr,
  iteration,
  seq_nbr,
  emp_id_key
FROM
  SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP emp
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        SJTCAPP.LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP emp2
      WHERE
        emp2.emp_id_key = emp.emp_id_key AND
        emp2.iteration < emp.iteration AND
        emp2.seq_nbr < emp.seq_nbr
    )
```

Comment: I think that is the right direction to look.  When I tried that query by itself I still returned the extra employees.  My goal would be to have only one employee for each iteration/sequence pair.
RPT_NBR ITERATION SEQ_NBR EMP_ID_KEY
1572413 1 2 282167
1572413 1 1 282167
1572413 1 2 44746
1572413 1 1 44746
1572413 1 2 227225
1572413 1 1 227225

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going back to using a GROUP BY

```
left join (
    select min(rpt_nbr) as rpt_nbr, min(iteration) as iteration, min(seq_nbr) as seq_nbr, min(emp_id_key) as emp_id_key from LAB_RPT_SPEC_EMP group by rpt_nbr, iteration, seq_nbr
    ) se
    on se.rpt_nbr = s.rpt_nbr and se.seq_nbr = s.seq_nbr and se.iteration = s.iteration
```